# PostgreSQL column "id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist SQL state: 42703

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, cascade

I have a table named 'country'. with an identity column called 'id'

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.country
    ADD COLUMN "id " integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 );
```

I also have a table named 'county' in which  I have a reference to the id of the previous table 'country_id'

When I am trying to set cascade actions

```
ALTER TABLE county
DROP CONSTRAINT country_id,
ADD CONSTRAINT country_id
FOREIGN KEY (country_id)
REFERENCES country (id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

I get back
'column "id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist SQL state: 42703'

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot!

I have tried the same code for other tables and it worked.

Comment: The new column in table `public.country` is not called `"id "` with a trailing space. It also is lacking a primary key or unique constraint. Avoid quoted identifiers!